# How can I simulate IPv6 on my iOS app without using a thunderbolt cable

Tags: ios, macos, testing, ipv6

I'm trying to test my app under IPv6 network conditions.
I tried following the tutorial here
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16

which says "Make sure your Mac is connected to the Internet, but not through Wi-Fi." I don't currently have any other method of connecting the Mac to internet.  How may I still test the app under IPv6 network conditions?

Comment: You could try USB tethering to an iPhone with personal hotspot enabled, but I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: A USB Ethernet dongle?

Comment: That might work but I'm looking more for a software solution to this rather than acquiring new hardware.

Comment: You don't have the hardware that would make a software solution possible. That's why you need new hardware.